# JSON to JSON changing array to one long string using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

Lets say my JSON input is:

```json
{
  "rating": {
    "primary": {
      "value": [ "a", "B", 1]
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

```json
{
  "values": "a, B, 1"
}
```

I'm using jolt JSON to JSON code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with stock transformations of Jolt. You need to write your custom transformation. Check the documentation section on how to write your own transformations.

Comment: Yep, that would be a custom Java transform.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "value": "=concat(@(2,rating.primary.value[0]),',',@(2,rating.primary.value[1]),',',@(2,rating.primary.value[2]))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "rating": ""
    }
  }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can use a **modify** transformation spec along with a ***join*** function to concatenate the components of the array as desired as follows

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value": "=join(', ',@(1,&))" 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of extra wrappers while renaming to "values"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value": "&s" // the literal "value" is replicated by &
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where **`@(1,&)`** replicates the value(while *overwriting* the original value) of the current attribute(**`"value"`**) which is stated at the right-hand side of the current level, the **1** followed by the opening bracket represents this.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]