# Convert an Array to Comma separated String in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to convert an array to comma separated string using jolt transform.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
{
    "scores": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e"
    ]
}
```

Expected Output

```
{
    "scores": "a,b,c,d,e"
}
```

Comment: Language tag? Jolt is java? Where's your code?

Comment: And is this not the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707768/json-to-json-changing-array-to-one-long-string-using-jolt

Comment: Jolt may be implemented in Java, but a language tag "Jolt" can be understood as a reference to the Jolt DSL used to configure the transformations.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following spec

[{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",

"spec": {
      "scores":"=concat(@(2,scores[0]),',',@(2,scores[1]),',',@(2,scores[2]),',',@(2,scores[3]),',',@(2,scores[4]))"
    }
 }

]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` with `modify-overwrite-beta` operation.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "scores": "=join(', ',@(1,scores))"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]